# How can a Spring bean detect if it itself has been wrapped in an AOP proxy?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop

We are using Spring's `TransactionInterceptor` to set some database partition information using `ThreadLocal` whenever a DAO method marked with the `@Transactional` annotation is executed.  We need this to be able to route our queries to different database partitions.

This works fine for most DAO methods:

```
// this causes the invoke method to set a thread-local with the host name of
// the database server the partition is on
@Transactional
public int deleteAll() throws LocalDataException {
```

The problem is when we need to reference the DAO *proxy* object itself inside of the DAO.  Typically we have to have the caller pass in the proxy-dao:

```
public Pager<Foo, Long> getPager(FooDao proxyDao) {
```

This looks like the following in code which is obviously gross.

```
fooDao.getPager(fooDao);
```

The problem is that when we are inside of FooDao, the `this` is *not* the proxy DAO that we need.

Is there a better mechanism for a bean to discover that it has a proxy wrapper around it?  I've looked at the [Spring AOPUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils.html) but I see no way to find the proxy for an object.  I don't want `isAopProxy(...)` for example.  I've also read the [Spring AOP docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html) but I can't see a solution there unless I implement my own AOP native code which I was hoping to avoid.

I suspect that I might be able to inject the DAO into itself with a `ApplicationContextAware` utility bean and a `setProxyDao(...)` method, but that seems like a hack as well.  Any other ideas how I can detect the proxy so I can make use of it from within the bean itself?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is using native Aspectj load/compile time weaving not an option at all - then the advice will weave into the proxy and you should not be having an issue of proxy and this reference within the proxy?

Comment: `this` won't do @Thorbjørn because as the post states, I need the proxy _not_ the bean itself.

Comment: Writing my own native AOP may be my only solution @Biju.  I was hoping to avoid it if I can.  Thanks tho.

Comment: Absolutely @Thorbjørn.  There is no way to replace or wrap `this`.  The bean itself sees `this` and _not_ the proxy that everyone else gets injected with.  That's how AOP works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hacky solution along the lines of what you have suggested, considering that AspectJ compile time or load time weaving will not work for you:

Create an interface along these lines:

```
public interface ProxyAware<T> {
    void setProxy(T proxy);
}
```

Let your Dao's implement the ProxyAware implementation, now create a BeanPostProcessor with an Ordered interface to run last, along these lines:

```
public class ProxyInjectingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (AopUtils.isAopProxy((bean))){
            try {
                Object target = ((Advised)bean).getTargetSource().getTarget();
                if (target instanceof ProxyAware){
                    ((ProxyAware) target).setProxy(bean);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

It is ugly, but works.

Comment: I ended up removing the `Ordered` because it seemed to have an adverse affect on my AOP for some reason.  But otherwise it is working.  Maybe you should delete the `Ordered`?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

There is a handy static utility [`AopContext.currentProxy()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopContext.html#currentProxy%28%29) method provided by Spring which returns a proxy to object from which it was called.

Although using it is considered a bad practice, semantically the same method exists in Java EE as well: [`SessionContext.getBusinessObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject%28java.lang.Class%29).

I wrote few articles about this utility method and various pitfalls: [1](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2009/09/spring-aop-riddle-demystified.html), [2](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2009/08/spring-aop-riddle.html), [3](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2011/10/spring-pitfalls-proxying.html).

Comment: I started to say that I wasn't _in_ a proxy when I make the call so there is no current proxy.  But there is no reason why I couldn't mark the `getPager()` method as being `@Transactional` in which case I would be.  So this is helpful @Tomasz.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use Spring to inject a bean reference into the bean, even the same bean, just as you would for any other bean reference. No special action required.

The presence of such a variable explicitly acknowledges in the class design that the class expects to be proxied in some manner. This is not necessarily a bad thing, as aop can change behavior that breaks the class contract.

The bean reference would typically be for an interface, and that interface could even be a different one for the self-referenced internal methods.

Keep it simple. That way lies madness. :-)

More importantly, be sure that the semantics make sense. The need to do this may be a code smell that the class is mixing in multiple responsibilities best decomposed into separate beans.

Comment: Thanks Kent.  I was hoping to not have to do that injection into all of my DAOs.  The `BeanPostProcessor` seems to be working but I'll keep this in mind.